# Where start with appendix

Tags: appendices

I'm trying to work with `appendix` package, but it is a mess...I have too many problems and I didn't find any ready styles. Can someone say where to start with these problems:
First: page numbering have to be like:

```
appendix I
appendix II
appendix III,1
appendix III,2
appendix III,3
appendix IV
```

Maybe if all the appendix are different files and page numbering can be done like from there.
Second: In table of contents should appendix should look like this:

```
2 Section..........................3
3 Section text.....................6
References.........................7
Appendices
          Appendix I: Appendix test
          Appendix II: Appendix two
          Appendix III: Test
          Appendix IV: Hello world
```

And every Figure and table numbering have to be reset.

Like in the picture, where first you can see the table of contents, where the appendix are at the end.
After that there is example of Appendix pages and page numbering. Page number should right corner.
I got it almost right with this:

```
\fancyhead[R]{Appendix \thesection \ifnum\value{page}>0\relax, \thepage\else\fi}
```

Only problem is, when there is more than one page, then it will not print the first number. 
[image]
Is this even possible?

Comment: can you please add a minimal example of your code?

Comment: I don't have any yet

Answer (score 2):

Here's a 'template' does tries to setup the (somewhat) unclear specifications. Problems might occur with `hyperref`, however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc]{appendix}  % Adding the name `Appendix` before each toc entry with titletoc and adding a separate line for Appendices with `toc` 

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\section{Second}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{My dummy figure in the regular section}
\end{figure}

\section{Third}

\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}% Reset the figure counter
\counterwithin{table}{section} % Reset the table counter
%\counterwithin*{page}{section} % Reset the page counter with each appendix section 

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecindent}{10pt}}
\section{First Appendix}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{My dummy figure in the appendix}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\section{Second Appendix}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Third Appendix}
\blindtext[15]
\section{Fourth Appendix}
\blindtext[5]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not quite, but it help me to get forward. (y) I update the question description. I hope this will describe better what I have to have

Comment: @pinq-: This is precisely the reason why **you** should provide a clear description of the issue/request and just a fragment or 'I want to have this' - statement. Now I can start again :-(

Comment: I try to do example in to text, but it wasn't clear enough :/